# regular expression new line between tags

Tags: php, regex

I have a php code with regular expression in it and it fails on the new line in the p tag within the li tag. When i execute this code it removes `</ul></li>` from it.

```
<?php
$data   =   "<h1>test</h1>
            <h2>test</h2>
            <p>This is not real text but just a test, This is not real text but just a test, This is not real text but just a test, This is not real text but just a test, This is not real text but just a test</p>
            <ul><li><p>This is not real text but just a test, This is not real text but just a test, This is not real text but just a test, This is not real text but just a test</p>
            </li></ul>
            <ul><li><p>This is not real text but just a test, This is not real text but just a test, This is not real text but just a test, This is not real text but just a test</p>
            </li></ul>";

$pattern    =   "#[\<ul\>\<li\>]*\<[p]*[h1]*[h2]*[h3]*\>(.+?)\</[p]*[h1]*[h2]*[h3]*\>[\</li\>\</ul\>]*#is";
preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $output);
var_dump($output);
?>
```

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: just a question - what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: First - do **NOT** parse HTML with regex. Second - you never ever code a regex, correct?

Comment: looks like you are very confused about regular expression syntax. `[\<ul\>\<li\>]` is equivalent to `[<>ilu]`, it matches any of the characters between the brackets.  if you are trying to match any of `<ul>` or `<li>`, you should use `<(ul|li)>`.  similarly with `[h1]`, that things matches either `h` or `1`.

Comment: It removes the `</ul></li>` tags because they are on a new line, how can i prevent that.

Comment: Jaap: that regular expression is completely out of whack.  you can prevent whatever misfeature you are observing by starting with a clean sheet.  play with individual constructions such as character classes, subpatterns, and quantifiers in isolation, to get a feel for their effects.  only then get back to your present task.  and seriously, throw away this nonsensical regex.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but I think to correct pattern would be something like this:

```
#\s*(<ul><li>)?(\s*<(p|h1|h2|h3)>)*(.+?)(</(p|h1|h2|h3)>\s*)*(</li></ul>)?#is
```

EDIT: Corrected one mistake

Comment: "#(<(ul|li)>)*(.*?)<(p|h1|h2|h3)>(.+?)</(p|h1|h2|h3)>(.*?)(</(ul|li)>)*#is" this worked for me now let me try yours